# Enigmail not asking for pgp passphrase but saying no key available

Tags: thunderbird, decryption, enigmail

decrypting emails with enigmail in thunderbird does not work anymore.
It is because I don't get the chance to punch in my passphrase, a form asking me to do so used to pop up, now it's not and I'm getting this message:

> Error - no matching private/secret key found to decrypt message; click on 'Details' button for more information

The private key is available though, since

```
gpg -d Desktop/mail.eml
```

makes the form appear. After filling in my passphrase I can read the decrypted mail within the terminal.

Another hint for a problem with the passphrases appeared when I created to new keys today. I could not create a revocation certificate because there was no passphrase set. Which, again, is not true.

I first noticed the problem on Monday, August 31st.

I checked the internet for a bit and then did the following:

1. Make sure an instance of gpg-agent is running:

   ```
   gpg-agent -v
   ```

   returns

   ```
   gpg-agent: gpg-agent running and available
   ```

   Content of .gnupg/gpg-agent.conf:

   > default-cache-ttl 0
   >   max-cache-ttl 0
2. Go to `dconf Editor desktop->gnome->crypto->cache` and set `gpg-cache-ttl` to `0`
3. `Thunderbird Enigmail->Clear Saved Passphrases` gives an Enigmail Alert saying:

   > You are using gpg-agent for passphrase handling. Clearing the passphrase is therefore not possible from within Enigmail.

   `Thunderbird Enigmail->Preferences->Basic Remember passphrase for 0 minutes of idle time`
4. Make `gpg-agent` forget my passphrase:

   ```
   pkill -SIGHUP gpg-agent
   ```
5. `Seahorse->GnuPG keys` delete all keys and reimport them

None of that list made any difference to the problem. I wonder, how do I get Enigmail to ask for my passphrase again?

Thanks in advance!
Bronk

**Edit**

1. Removing `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-gpg.desktop` didn't do anything.
2. Removing `seahorse` didn't do anything.
3. Using `decrypt-file`:

   ```
   Couldn't decrypt file: mail.eml.pgp
   Bad passphrase
   ```

Comment: Install `pinentry-gtk2` on Ubuntu with Unity

Comment: I have this problem, too, but oddly I can sign my own emails, but it gives your same message when I try decrypting messages signed with my pubkey.

Answer (score 7):

Try this: https://www.enigmail.net/support/gnupg2_issues.php
In my case, I need install a grafical version of pinentry (pinentry-qt4 package).

"Resolving issues with GnuPG 2.x and gpg-agent

Note GnuPG 2.x requires an "agent" to handle passphrases. By default this is done by gpg-agent, but there are other tools implementing a subset of its functionality. These instructions are for gpg-agent only. If you use an agent like gnome-keyring, seahorse-agent or the KDE Wallet Manager, then these instructions don't apply.
Most common Problem

Symptoms

The most common issue is that gpg-agent (a part of GnuPG) cannot launch pinentry (the tool used to query your passphrase). Enigmail would display messages like:

```
when reading messages:
Error - no matching private/secret key found to decrypt message; click on 'Details' button for more information

when sending messages:
- Send operation aborted. Error - encryption command failed
- Send operation aborted. Key 0x....... not found or not valid. The (sub-)key might have expired
```

How to Analyze

```
Try sending a signed and unencrypted message to yourself.
Check the output in the Enimgail log: go to menu Enigmail > Debugging Options > View Log.
Search for the following text: parseErrorOutput: status message. You will probably find this message several times. Check what follows below.
If the message says something like "no pinentry", "problem with the agent", "Invalid IPC response" or "problem with gpg-agent", then there is something wrong with your gpg-agent and/or pinentry setup.
```

How to Fix it

```
Execute the following script from a terminal to find out if a graphical version of pinentry is used:

pinentry <<EOT
SETDESC Hello World
CONFIRM
EOT

You should get a graphical window with a confirmation message "Hello World". If a "window" is opened within your terminal window then pinentry is text-based, which does not work with Enigmail. To fix this, ensure that a graphical version of pinentry is installed. On Linux/Unix systems, these would typically be pinentry-qt/pinentry-qt4 or pinentry-gtk/pinentry-gtk2, and on Mac OS X pinentry-mac. Rename the existing pinentry file to "pinentry-text" or similar, and create a symlink from pinentry-qt, pinentry-qt4, pinentry-gtk, pinentry-gtk2 or pinentry-mac to pinentry. Then restart your PC.

If the above does not help, check the contents of $HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf. Make sure that there is a configuration entry pinentry-program containing the full path to a graphical version of pinentry as above. E.g.:

pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-gtk

Then save the file and restart your PC.

If you still can't access your key, then execute the following script from a terminal:

gpg-connect-agent <<EOT
GETINFO version
EOT

The output should be something like the text below, where 2.0.26 represents the agent version number. The version number should match your gpg version number:

D 2.0.26
OK

If you get an error message like "ERR 280 not implemented" then you don't use gpg-agent, but one of the alternatives like gnome-keyring. We recommend you switch to gpg-agent by disabling your current agent. See e.g. askubuntu for how to disable gnome-keyring or how to disable KDE wallet.

If you get a useful result from above, then execute the following script from a terminal:

gpg-connect-agent <<EOT
GET_CONFIRMATION Hello
EOT

Pinentry should now open as a graphical window (just like above), with the difference to the step above that this instance of pinentry was launched from gpg-agent. If this is successful, then GnuPG 2 should work correctly in Enigmail.

If gpg-agent still cannot launch pinentry from Enigmail, then you need to start debugging gpg-agent. Execute the following commands from a terminal:

killall gpg-agent
gpg-agent --debug-level expert --use-standard-socket --daemon /bin/sh

This will start gpg-agent from the command line, open a new shell and print the debug output to that shell. If the command succeeded, you will see somehting like:
gpg-agent[76979]: gpg-agent 2.0.26 started
Leave the terminal window untouched, start Thunderbird and try to use Enigmail. As you'll try to access gpg-agent, you will see the output in your terminal window. If gpg-agent cannot start pinentry successfully, you will see something like this:

gpg-agent[76993]: starting a new PIN Entry
gpg-agent[76993]: chan_19 <- ERR 67109133 can't exec `/usr/bin/pinentry': No such file or directory
gpg-agent[76993]: chan_19 -> BYE
gpg-agent[76993]: can't connect to the PIN entry module: IPC connect call failed
gpg-agent[76993]: command get_passphrase failed: No pinentry

Press Ctrl+D in the terminal to end the debugging session. The bold line should tell you the reason for the error (in the example above, pinentry cannot be found). Try to fix the error and repeat the test."
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The last bit says "If gpg-agent still cannot launch pinentry from Enigmail, then..." - but IF pinentry is launched correctly, but the decryption does still not work, the guide does not help here...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but found that killing gpg-agent was a workround.

(From the source code I found that you can enable enigmail logging by editing the "defaults/preferences/enigmail.js" file somewhere under ~/.thunderbird, setting the "extensions.enigmail.logDirectory" property to "/tmp". The log file "/tmp/enigdbug.txt" then showed the full gpg command that enigmail was running, ending with "--use-agent". I ran that gpg command from the command-line, feeding it an encrypted email message. It complained with the error message "gpg: problem with the agent: No PINentry". Googling for that error message turned up the suggestion to kill the gpg-agent. Meanwhile, the NSA rubs its hands in glee that the user experience of PKI encryption is so rubbish.)

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP. Perversely, running the exact command found in enigdbug.txt yields perfect results. :\

Comment: Did not help here. Although, `gpg -d message.eml` hat the same problem: `gpg: public key decryption failed: No passphrase given` - without asking me for a passphrase

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Thunderbird was asking again and again to put in my key's password and Gnome keyring wouldn't remember it, although I asked it to. The problem was, that `gpg-agent` wasn't running in my session. The problem vanished when I manually started it in the current session with:

```
gpg-agent --debug-level expert --use-standard-socket --daemon /bin/sh
```

To solve the problem permanently you have to assure, that the agent is running in your session:
1. Check you have the following file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90gpg-agent`. Mine looks like this:

```
  : ${GNUPGHOME=$HOME/.gnupg}

  GPGAGENT=/usr/bin/gpg-agent
  PID_FILE="$GNUPGHOME/gpg-agent-info-$(hostname)"

  if grep -qs '^[[:space:]]*use-agent' "$GNUPGHOME/gpg.conf" "$GNUPGHOME/options" &&
     test -x $GPGAGENT &&
     { test -z "$GPG_AGENT_INFO" || ! $GPGAGENT 2>/dev/null; }; then

     if [ -r "$PID_FILE" ]; then
         . "$PID_FILE"
     fi

     # Invoking gpg-agent with no arguments exits successfully if the agent
     # is already running as pointed by $GPG_AGENT_INFO
     if ! $GPGAGENT 2>/dev/null; then
         STARTUP="$GPGAGENT --daemon --sh --write-env-file=$PID_FILE $STARTUP"
     fi
  fi
```

2. Check you have the file `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`, with at least the following line:

   ```
   use-agent
   ```

If not, you can add it with the following command:

```
echo "use-agent" >>  ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

Comment: `use-agent` is not needed any more in OpenGPG 2.1 - the agent is used in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error error about pinentry. At the end, I figured out that the gpg-agent was using the wrong pinentry. Solved it by setting the right pinentry by editing *~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf* and adding the following line

```
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2
```

Default for the system I'm working at was pinentry-x11(it's an company wide installation which allows a variety of window managers), which did not work for gnome3. - So one has to make sure that the gpg-agent is using the correct pinentry for the actual window manager in use.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just that I didn't have any `pinentry` tools except for `pinentry-curses` (command line with pointer support). So in Fedora install any of these passphrase/PIN entry dialogs:

- `pinentry-qt.x86_64` based on Qt4;
- `pinentry-gtk.x86_64` based on GTK+;
- `pinentry-emacs.x86_64` for emacs;
- `pinentry-gnome3.x86_64` for GNOME 3.

I used the GNOME 3 `pinentry` package.

Answer (score 0):

In thunderbird, select the message, click on the hamburger, expand the Enigmail menu and select decrypt/verify. You'll get a password prompt after which the message will be decrypted.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference...

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you not get the password prompt, or is the message not decrypted?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem!
Following the gpg-agent debug done with:

```
gpg-agent --debug-level expert --use-standard-socket --daemon /bin/sh
```

I found out that something was broken between enigmail and gpg and it never asked for a passphrase.
But in the case the passphrase was pre-loaded all worked perfectly.

In my case the problem what that, in the past, I forced the follow option in the ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf

```
pinentry-mode loopback
```

This broke the process. You can check the command that enigmail is running enabling the expert mode in Enigmail and then in "Debugging Options --> View Console"

Commented and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Ubuntu Budgie 18.04. For some reason `pinentry-gnome3` didn't display a dialog.

I could solve the issue by installing `pinentry-fltk` and also selecting it in update-alternatives:

```
sudo apt-get install pinentry-fltk
sudo update-alternatives --config pinentry
```

In the shown dialog select `usr/bin/pinentry-fltk`

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative pinentry (providing /usr/bin/pinentry).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3   90        auto mode
* 1            /usr/bin/pinentry-fltk     70        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3   90        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```