# GPG/Agent does not ask for password

Tags: gnome, encryption, thunderbird, gnupg, enigmail

I'm a bit frustrated by my Ubuntu (17.04) Setup with Enigmail 1.9.7/GPG 2.1.15. I think after changing from Ubuntu/Unity to Ubuntu GNOME (but I really don't know if that was the trigger), Enigmail stopped working: I can't decrypt incoming encrypted emails any more. I am not asked for my GPG key password, pinentry (despite generally working in tests) skips prompting for the password and gpg-agent just tells me that there was no password given.

Thunderbird/Enigmail tells me "Missing Passphrase", that's where I started. I then debugged the problem down as far as I could, using [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670908/enigmail-not-asking-for-pgp-passphrase-but-saying-no-key-available#687002), [the official Enigmail troubleshooting guide](https://www.enigmail.net/index.php/en/faq?view=topic&id=14#faqLink_2) and many, many more links and guides.

- I CAN sign mails (sent to myself as test), verifying them is no problem within Thunderbird.
- I can send encrypted Mails to myself; the received Mail has a info from Enigmail that the passphrase is missing:
  [image: screenshot]
- All the pinentry tests from [the Enigmail troubleshooting guide](https://www.enigmail.net/index.php/en/faq?view=topic&id=14#faqLink_2) are ok, I see the GNOME styled pinentry dialog.
- My `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` contains a `use-agent' line (**even if that is not needed any more in GPG 2.1**)
- My `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` contains a line `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gnome3` - even `pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry` works here, as it automatically detects the `DISPLAY/x11/GNOME` it seems.

I've started a gpg-agent using `gpg-agent --debug-level expert  --daemon /bin/sh`, logging all gpg agent activities, which outputs while trying to decrypt:

```
gpg-agent[22794]: DBG: chan_4 -> INQUIRE PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 22797
gpg-agent[22794]: DBG: chan_4 <- END
gpg-agent[22794]: DBG: error calling pinentry: No passphrase given <GPG Agent>
gpg-agent[22794]: failed to unprotect the secret key: No passphrase given
gpg-agent[22794]: failed to read the secret key
gpg-agent[22794]: command 'PKDECRYPT' failed: No passphrase given
gpg-agent[22794]: DBG: chan_4 -> ERR 67109041 No passphrase given <GPG Agent>
gpg-agent[22794]: DBG: chan_4 <- [eof]
```

If I save the encrypted mail to an eml file and do a `gpg -d file.eml` manually. Same result as before:

```
$ gpg -d FM.eml 
gpg: encrypted with 4096-bit RSA key, ID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, created XXXX-XX-XX
      "Christian Gonzalez <xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: No passphrase given
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Editing `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` and removing the line

```
default-key XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

did help in the first place, but after a system restart, the old problem returned.

Does anyone have a hint for me?

Maybe it has to do with Ubuntu's "peculiarity" in using Gnome-Keyring as agent? Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I removed the default `pinentry` package, namely `pinentry-gnome3`, and  installed `pinentry-qt` instead, and now enigma does prompt me for the pass. I hope it works for you.

Comment: To remove `pinentry-gnome3`, about 12 packages are removed and 43 installed (`kinit kio kwalletmanager libgpgmepp6 libkf5attica5 libkf5completion-data  libkf5completion5 libkf5crash5 libkf5dbusaddons-bin,...`), even if `pinentry-qt` is installed before. This can't be serious.

Comment: I am no expert in this. I had the same issue where enigma stopped asking for a password and got the same log trace like you. It was just a random roll of dice for me but it did work.

Comment: But you removed pinentry-gnome3 *first*, and *afterwords* installed pinentry-qt? So you uninstalled a bunch of dependent packages?

Comment: Further, when I want to uninstall `pinentry-gnome3`, apt wants to install `kinit kio kwalletmanager libgpgmepp6`etc. as well !?!

Comment: I dont remember if that was the case for me.  In anycase you can reinstall gnome3 if other pinentry does not work for you. Make sure to run `gpgconf --kill gpg-agent` to restart the agent before testing with the new pinentry.

Comment: I hade the same issue on Debian 10. Thanks for the fix

Answer (score 0):

I've added those lines to the `~/.xinitrc` file and it works again:

```
if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
        for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
                [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
        done
        unset f
fi
```

Comment: I'll test next time I have the problem. I reinstalled Ubuntu. Greets from Salzburg too.